# Import typings for google gapi in JavaScriptServices

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core

I have a [JavaScriptServices-aspnetcore-spa](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) application (ASP.NET core & Angular 2). I would like to add Google SignIn button. There are plenty code examples on SO, but all use `declare const gapi: any;`. I would like to see typings (`declare const gapi: gapi;`) so I install:

```
npm install --save @types/gapi
npm install --save @types/gapi.auth2
```

I get 2 directories with typings in `node_modules\@types\`.
Then I change

> ClientApp/tsonfig.json

from `"types": [ "node"` ], to `"types": [ "node", "gapi", "gapi.auth2" ]`,
but without success.
I found somewhere I should `import "gapi";` but gapi is still not defined:

> ERROR in ./ClientApp/app/common/pages/login.ts (11,21): error TS2304:
>   Cannot find name 'gapi'.

Any idea? Maybe the problem is that tsconfig.json is placed inside ClientApp folder, but I don't think so, because if it works (types property in `tsconfig.json`) for `node`, it should also for `gapi` and `gapi.auth2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `declare const gapi: gapi;` did the trick.

It seems that if you include typings, there is no need (or better say forbidden) to declare const.